# What is the Java RegEx equivalent to the SQL LIKE clause of "%A%B%"?

Tags: java, regex

What is the Java RegEx equivalent to the SQL LIKE clause of "%A%B%"?

Pretty basic question, I'm just learning the Java Regex flavor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is it pattern wise: `.*A.*B.*`

I'll edit and add more for specific java calls.

EDIT #1:

```
//simplest match
"".matches( ".*A.*B.*" );

String foo = "";
foo.matches( ".*A.*B.*" );
```

EDIT #2:
From the [API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*A.*B.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("your-string-here");
boolean b = m.matches();
```

Also, I would take a look at [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), its not free but it does have means to generate snippets for many languages, test & parse regex's, etc.

Comment: @javamonkey79: Don't you have to make it non-greedy using question marks?

Comment: I'm not sure. My interpretation of the SQL like is "any characters, then A, then any characters, then B, then any characters". If you have a good explanation with the non-greedy I'd love to read and upvote it :)

Comment: @javamonkey79: `.*` means "take every char until you hit the end". When you write `.*A`, it means "take every char until you hit the end and then look for an A". As you already matched everything greedily using `.*`, no `A` is left and the pattern doesn't match on, for example, "A".

Comment: @thejh: sorry for the noformat: This returns true for me:   String regex = ".*A";
  System.out.println( "A".matches( regex ) );

Comment: @thejh - Not true. `.*A` will match "A" because the regex engine will backtrack if the `.*` matches "too much". The difference between greedy and non-greedy only comes into play if you use parentheses to capture matches.

Answer (score 0):

It is ".*?A.*?B.*"
If you use .* without ? it matches whole string because . (dot) means "any character", * means 0 - infinity times.

Comment: I thought '.?' in java only matches once or not at all. Isn't thejh more correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?A.*?B.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
...
```